# Dvd-Rom is missing how can i bring it back?

Tags: dvd

I am new at ubuntu i clicked the button in the pic now dvd rom is missing how can i bring it back? [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta0pk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open en close the DVD player with a DVD in it.

It will have you show the icon again. The DVD icon only show when you insert  a DVD and did not "unmount" it.